# Certain Fraction between Fractions

Tags: fractions

Is there always a fraction $\frac{r}{s}$ with $\frac{p}{q}<\frac{r}{s}<\frac{p+1}{q}$ and $s<q$ for $0<p<q-1\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It's an interesting question.  If both are in lowest terms then you can always use Farey sequences to show they aren't neighbors.  I can't sort out what happens when one (or both) can reduce.

Comment: Well, I tried to come up with a counter-example. Do you think it is a true statement?

Comment: If you made me bet right now I'd say, yes it is true.   Looking at the Farey sequences of modest lengths it was always easy to insert fractions the way you want.  Of course that isn't a proof.  Could easily be an accident of small numbers.

Comment: @user255536: You may want to add that $s\gt 0$ because you can take $r=-2q,s=-2p-1$ for the current form.

Comment: @mathlove.  Agreed.  We need to require that both r and s are > 0.

Comment: @user255536 did not define r thus if I take r>>s it will almost always to be false

Answer (score 2):

Since $0\lt p\lt q-1$, we have
$$
\frac pq\lt\frac p{q-1}\lt\frac{p+1}q
$$

Comment: Good!  Thanks.  Aside from being overkill, my methods weren't even working!